# EXTRACT only valid TO_NUMBER values from a field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table that contains TO_CHAR (numbers) in it. I need to remove those from the HAVE table and get them into the WANT table. I'll appreciate your help in accomplishing this

HAVE

```
CoL_A
A002B11
C19B234
1
2
3
7
123455
H1VITA
2WTYUW
```

WANT

```
CoL_A
1
2
3
7
123455
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
select *
from YOUR_TABLE
where REGEXP_LIKE( COL_A, '^[[:digit:]]*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think REGEXP_REPLACE will meet your needs.

```
select regexp_replace('a1b2c3d4','[[:alpha:]]','') from dual;
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't solve your use case at all, I mis-read it.  Leaving for posterity. Use @Arun's solution.